# focus event on a table cell

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a table cell like:

```
<td>
    <div style="position:relative">
      <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
         <br>
      </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I am registering focus event on editable div as:

```
$(".editable").on("focus", function() {
       alert("focus event is called");
   });
```

but this is not working. Please help.

Comment: make sure you are calling it in dom ready

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v2QmM/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).on("focus",".editable", function() {
       alert("focus event is called");
   });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/RfDU7/)

Comment: focus event does not bubble up so event delegation will not work... you need to use [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusin)

Answer (score 0):

For `focus` to work on a div, it must have a `tabindex`.

So for your example to work,

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true" tabindex='1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div contenteditable="true" style="width:100px;height:100px;" class="editable">
    </div>
</div>
apply some css
```

Answer (score 0):

@OP - your original code works fine - maybe you were getting lots of alerts (clicking on the alert OK button blurs and re-focuses on the div) and then accepting the browser's suggestion to turn off alerts?

Try a different way of checking that the event is detected:

HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div class="editable" style="border : 1px solid black" contenteditable="true">
     <br>
  </div>
</div>

            <textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(".editable").on("focus", function() {
   $("#area").html("focused");
});

$(".editable").on("blur", function() {
   $("#area").html("blurred");
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cuYBD/

Click in and out of the divs and you should see the result you were looking for.